# How to LINQ Join when one key is an ArrayOfInt and the other an int

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get a list of messages from the database where one of the recipients of the message matches a user. Normally, if there was only one recipient, you would have something like the following

```
var res = db.messages.Where(m => m.id == message_id)
               .Join(db.persons, m => m.recipients, p => p.id, (m, p) => new {m, p})
               .Select(x => new Message(){ msg = x.m, person = x.p})
```

But what if recipients is a comma seperated string of integers and id is an integer?

Comment: It can't be done.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/d2791ad4-3897-4fc0-80e9-72ebc4822898

Comment: The following may be useful information as well, http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert recipients into a list of elements as a start. I'm assuming that recipients is a list of ids from the person table.  As such from your question you have to pass in the person id to do a select on it?

```
var messages=db.messages.Select(
        m => m.id == message_id && 
        (m.recipients.Split(",").
            Any(recipient => reipient == person_id)
        )

var person = db.Persons.Select(p => p.id == person_id)
```

Note that doing this in linq is going to suffer a performance penalty as things like .Split are C# and will not work on IQueryable.  As such the DB will have to transmit up a lot of data to perform this query depending on the size of your table.  If you have a view on the database when you have tokenized this out, or you are capable of creating a new table in the DB where the recipients of a message are listed with a message ID, you could do this much more easily (not to mention normalising your DB in the process).

Comment: I'll give that a try but how do I access p ? Yes, creating a new table would be the easier alternative but I just wanted to find out if the join is possible with the existing structure.

If the results are cached, then the performance penalty will be lessened?

Comment: I'm also thinking that using the query syntax, using a .Contains() may just do the trick but wondering how do you do it in lambda

Comment: Your query was fetching a message for given person ids?  That query was this.  Are you after the list of people that a given message was addressed to? That is a different query...

Comment: I'm trying to get a message which recipients contains a person id and at the same time get some information on that person. That is why I need the p

Comment: BTW, There is no person_id, the only input parameter is message_id

Comment: Given a message you want all the information on the people it was addressed too?  That is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - using Contains:

```
var res = from m in db.messages
          where m.id == message_id
          from p in db.persons
          where m.recipients.Split(",").Select(i => Int32.Parse(i))
                .Contains(p.id)
          select new Message() {
              msg = m,
              person = p
          };
```

The idea:

1. Get the messages as in your original query
2. Get all persons where contained in the recipient list
3. Continue with your original query

---

Option 2 - using a LINQ join (maybe more complicated than it needs to be):

```
var res = from m in db.messages
          where m.id == message_id
          from r in m.recipients.Split(",")
          select new {
              Message = m,
              Recipient = Int32.Parse(r)
          } into rec
          join p in db.persons on rec equals p.id
          select new Message () {
              msg = m,
              person = p
          };
```

The idea:

1. Get the messages as in your original query
2. Split the string into a list of Int32
3. Join this list against `db.persons`
4. Continue with your original query

---

Not sure which of these is faster, you'll have to check.

I would also shy away from using comma-delimited strings as a foreign key reference namely because of the troubles you're having here. They're ugly to look at and a true pain to manipulate. Instead, if you have control over the schema, consider a one-to-many relation table having `MessageId` and `PersonId`. Of course if you don't have control, you're stuck.

Disclaimer: These are untested, so may need some tweaking for the code to work. The algorithms however should be ok.

Comment: I initially oversimplified the query, it should be clearer now.

Comment: it would be nice if it was in lambda syntax but I'll give that a try. And probably no need the Parse, just a .ToString() on the person id would suffice?

Comment: Ok I cleaned up the end to match your select.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I get "Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'"

Comment: In that case, try the parse version?

Comment: Ok, I usually add the untested disclaimer but it looks like I forgot this time. I added it now.